# GitHub Action workflow not running

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action workflow file @ myrepo/.github/workflows/Build Webpage.yml it contains this:

```yaml
name: Webpage Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - webpage 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: setup node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
      with:
        node-version: '12'
    - name: install deps and predeploy
      run: |
        npm ci
        npm run predeploy
    - name: Deploy 
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@3.5.2
      with:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        BRANCH: gh-pages
        FOLDER: build
```

When I push to the webpage branch nothing happens in the actions tab at all I can't tell if I have a syntax error or if something is completely not set up correctly, I have in past on this repo had errors relating to syntax like `every step must define a 'uses' or 'run' key`  which to me shows Github does recognize the workflow

Comment: does github still complain about the syntax?

Comment: No, no matter what I push to nothing happens, no complaints no errors that I can see

Comment: If you are absolutely sure you are pushing to the `webpage` branch, and still the workflow is not being triggered, then you need to head over to the official [actions community](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/bd-p/actions) page and submit a bug report

Comment: If you want to debug it further, another option is to change the trigger to run on a [schedule](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events-schedule), and see if that triggers the workflow...

Comment: welp I tested to make sure, it comes up with the normal message on Github saying the branch was committed to, and nothing appears in the actions tab. I'll try ^

Comment: So changing to a schedule did run the job ( it did fail), I feel at this point I should also mention that the files for this workflow are only on my master branch, the webpage branch doesn't contain them as its a "separate" part of the project, I had a feeling this would be an issue if this is the case I don't know how to create the folder on the webpage branch

Comment: I don't think that should be an issue. As long as the workflow is in your default branch, it should be triggered, unless github has changed this policy... I should also add that there are some limitations to running actions on forked repositories, so be mindful of that

Comment: Ok, the repo isn't forked so should be good there, the workflow itself looks fine its just the trigger that's not working

Comment: [Looks like I'm wrong](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/GitHub-Workflow-not-getting-triggered-for-push-event-on-other/td-p/38270). You do need to put the workflow in all branches you want it to run on

Comment: ok in that case, I need to work out how to create a .github/workflows folder on the webpage branch, obviously, I have a .github folder locally but that doesn't get pushed up currently, I don't know if that's a git ignore thing or just a git behavior

Comment: Check output of `git ls-files` when you are on the `webpage` branch. If it does not list the `.github` folder then you have not added it, so you need to do `git add .github` or ensure that it is not ignored in your `.gitignore` file

Comment: found it was confused with basic git file... Im an idiot obvs XD, just pushed the workflow up and its running so that looks fine, so in short make sure the workflows on the branch you want it to run on. I thought I saw it in a doc somewhere but couldn't find it. Thanks a bunch

Comment: This error is caused because you have the dash '-' marks incorrect. There's some formatting error it doesn't like.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

So as found in the comment below the post itself, if you want the workflow to run on branch x the `.github` folder must be on branch x and any other branch you want to trigger the workflow from

Comment: We ran into this issue when migrating from another provider to github/github actions, with a branch that predated the migration. It was very confusing :)

Comment: This is a case that can be missed by many users. Just copy the .github folder to your local working branches.

Answer (score 247):

Is your branch `master` or `main`?

It might be silly in the future but as for October 2020 just **keep in mind that the default GitHub branch has been renamed from `master` to `main`** ([source](https://github.com/github/renaming)).

So if you are copypasting actions from elsewhere, make sure that you are targeting the correct branch (for new repos this means most of the time to replace `master` with  `main` in the  `.yml` workflow files).

If you are targeting the wrong branch, the name of the action will appear on GitHub but no actions will actually run.

Comment: Nailed it. I copied/pasted. My branch was main YAML file was master.

Comment: If you made this change but it wasn't fixed, also see [sachinkondana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932410/6791398): if the workflow file was all that changed, and wasn't included in `paths`, the workflow won't run until something matching `paths` is changed.

Comment: This happened to me. That's why this place is awesome. I spent an hour checking the official documentation, looking for a solution and your answer nailed it. Thanks

Comment: [[ FACEPALM ]] : This is exactly what I did.  Had me chasing my tail for quite some time.
Just went ahead and did this: 
` branches:` `[ "master", "main" ] `

Comment: Something similar happened to me. I had `.github/workflow` instead of `.github/workflows` . Hope this may help some.

Answer (score 189):

In my case there was a Github actions outage. Check https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: well, i just arrived here and now im wondering how to manually run a push/pr workflow

Comment: It's supposed to be a bar at the top of the list of workflow runs as described [in the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow), but I'm not actually seeing that right now…

Comment: This is the answer. Git actions is down right now!

Comment: @NickK9 maybe related: you need to have a `workflow_dispatch` trigger for the manual run button to be available.

Comment: Incredible how it happened to be the case yesterday as well. Maybe GitHub should be more reactive in notifying affected users.

Answer (score 31):

One more case, suppose if you already have `workflow` file inside project and if your `paths` set then the workflow will not RUN unless you make changes inside `path` folder. So if you make any changes to your `workflow` which kept outside of `path` won't trigger `Action`

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
     - master
    paths:
     - 'packages/container/**'
```

Answer (score 24):

- Another silly case scenario that happened to me. As the GitHub UI adds spaces to the folders path (sometimes this is caused by the Google Translate plugin), when I copied the path `.github/workflows` from the GitHub UI and used it to create folders in VSCode, it was `.github / workflows` with spaces around the `/`.

[image: GitHub workflow path]

- I caught this by asking GitHub to initialize the Actions workflow for me from the `Actions` tab, so I noticed my mistake, and **that's a good way to solve this issue.**

[image: GitHub Actions UI]

Comment: i wasnot making the exact mistake but using `workflow` instead of `workflows`. This comment helped me find the error. :D

Answer (score 19):

Just wanted to add a silly case scenario that happened to me. Whenever you add a new workflow, sometimes it may happen that workflow may not get into the running phase even after everything is specified correctly. **Just make sure to make some changes in whatever branch you are running the action in after adding the action itself. Make sure to commit these changes as well.** This will trigger the action to run and show up on the dashboard.

Comment: This just happened to me. I changed a workflow and it wouldn't trigger any runs. Changed a random unrelated file and then it worked again.

Answer (score 18):

Other possibility that can occur on a workflow is the following with `pull_request` type.

If there are conflicts with your branch and base branch, workflow will not trigger.  It's not always obvious because it's possible that the only conflicts you have is with workflows.

Just an example below, but main point is conflicts must be resolved first.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [labeled, reopened, synchronize, ready_for_review]
```

Comment: Daaamn...Thank you sir! Any source on this?

Comment: @IgorGonak just a long day of troubleshooting. :)

Comment: This is the case for me, I wish Github said "There's merge conflict so no actions will be run" instead of the confusing "Workflow runs completed with no jobs"

Answer (score 15):

A further trap to look out for: If you fork another repository which has a Github workflow, **workflows will be disabled in your fork by default.**

The intention of this feature is to prevent you from accidentally running an imported workflow with unknown behavior, which might pose a security hazard (e.g. by accessing secrets).

To re-enable workflows, go to the "Actions" tab of the repository and confirm that you understand the workflows you are about to enable.

Answer (score 12):

I found that my issue was described in the GitHub actions docs:

> If you define a branch with the ! character, you must also define at least one branch without the ! character. If you only want to exclude branches, use branches-ignore instead.

Originally, I had this in my workflow (which didn't trigger the action):

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "!main"
```

To fix it:

```
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - main
```

Comment: I'm curious, what's the usecase for pushing all branches except the main one?

Comment: @HashimAziz I don't recall exactly but maybe running some tests.

Answer (score 11):

The last gotcha to be aware, are the skip keywords in the commit that triggers the action.

> If any commit message in your push or the HEAD commit of your PR contains the strings [skip ci], [ci skip], [no ci], [skip actions], or [actions skip] workflows triggered on the push or pull_request events will be skipped.

I was bitten by that while working with Semantic Release and then resetting my deployment branches to the release commits. You can just reword the release commit and push (at least that's how I resolved it) in your deployment branch.

Answer (score 9):

Be aware that you can't have nested folders. For example, `.github/workflows/folder-1/my_workflow.yml`
will not be recognized by Github. In my case, I had to change it to `.github/workflows/my_workflow.yml`

Answer (score 6):

For me, accidentally had named the folder `.github/workspaces` instead of `.github/workflows`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case my workflow was not triggering because I was using double quotes inside a bash command which messed up the yml parsing.

You can check this on VSCode by seeing if the syntax highlighting looks off.

Answer (score 4):

If your commit is made by another action using the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN, the other workflow will not run.

You can fix this by creating a personal access token with write permission.

```yaml
name: Push changes
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have checked the branch and validated the actions, but the workflow isn't running. In that case, there's a high chance you need to **enable read and write permissions** from the relevant repository settings (top right corner) → Actions (left navigation bar) → General → Workflow permissions section.

[image: GitHub repository settings]
[image]
[image: GitHub repository settings read and write permissions]

Answer (score 2):

In my case what I needed to run a workflow in pylint branch but it was not working until I added the same workflow in the main branch.In the main branch I added `.github/workflows` and then the yml file of the workflow which I wanted to run.

Once this was done i went to the pylint branch and then in the workflow I added pylint under the branches. After doing this workflow was getting triggered after every commit

```
name: Python Notebooks Linting
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
      - 'pylint'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure your .yml file on push and pull_request is the right target. Look at your main branch first, is it master or main ?

```
on: 
  push:
    branches: [ main/master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main/master ]
```

Comment: Why duplicate the accepted answer from two years before?

Comment: This will trigger the workflow on pushes to a branch named "main/master" as written.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to merge your new workflow file into your Default branch for that repository. That was the only way I could get my workflow (for another branch) to appear on the GitHub Actions page.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the repo is new, make sure to wait 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The last possibility is that your workflow was automatically disabled because there was no update to the project in 90 days

I which case you need to go to the page of each specific workflow and click on the warning to reenable them (you will not see the warning in the `All workflows` page even if you only have one)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to go to "Actions" tab and see if your run was errored. In my case, the check was *pending* on the PR view, because I changed a secret name in one workflow, but forgot to change in the **calling** workflow.

However, when I went to "Actions" tab I saw that my workflow was unable to run because the ***inputs*** don't match although `required: true`.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue, the branch in my .yml (workflow file) file was not the branch I wanted to push to - as in git push origin "main" - right? For example, my "main" branch was where I was trying to push to whereas in my .yml file (workflow file) it had master in there. I changed it and everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Today I had this issue, the same yaml file was working fine in other branches, but not in my new one(feature/somename). The solution was to rename the branch without using the slash ("/")

Answer (score 1):

And another silly possibility to watch out for - I had something like

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'TTG-.*'
      - 'FRD-.*'
```

But it turns out that valid values for "branch expression" are *globs*, not regular expressions. So those periods in the branch names were being interpreted literally. I needed to change to

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'TTG-*'
      - 'FRD-*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your branch name have any of these characters in it: `+` `?` `!` `*` `**` ? and do you only run the workflow on pushes to that branch ?

Ours had these characters and so the workflow was not being triggered.  Once we escaped out these characters by adding `\` before them everything worked as expected.

Reference to GitHub documents here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore

Answer (score 1):

**Please double check everything**

Stupid mistake I made was naming a github folder with whitespace at the end, so on Github it was looking like `.github /workflows`(notice the space before the slash sign) instead of `.github/workflows`.

I have changed the folder name from `github`  to `github` and pushed, and the workflow started running immediately.

Answer (score 1):

this may sound a bit funny but sometimes the name of action also matter. For example in my case:

i changed a action named `pre-releases.yml` to `pre_releases.yml`

so my advice is keep name simple.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a silly answer to this. I had all files/folders starting with "." in my gitignore, so the workflow file itself wasn't in my repo. Fixed it, then it worked!
So, basically: **Check that your workflow file isn't in your gitignore**.