# AWS equivalent to cron for updating an S3 site based on python script every few hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cron, github-actions

I'm new to using AWS so bear with me.

I have a site hosted on S3 - it's an updating weather tracker map: index.html, data folder, and a python script to scrape and download files into that data folder.

I tried setting up github actions to run the scrape every few hours to update the map, but it doesn't trigger. I'm wondering how I could setup something similar on AWS and what the equivalent process would be? I don't understand if I need to set up Lambda or EventBridge, if someone could clarify my options and what the steps are, that would be super helpful!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Worth investigating why GitHub Action [doesn't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61989951/github-action-workflow-not-running) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565482/github-action-not-triggered-when-pushing-to-branch).

Answer (score 2):

EventBridge is the "cron" (it even supports cron format for the schedule), and AWS Lambda is the Python script. You would create an AWS Lambda function in Python, and configure EventBridge to trigger that function on a schedule.

I suggest reading [the official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html).